# Is there a term or phrase for the desire for Apocalypse?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm researching this for an article I'm writing: is there a term or phrase for the desire for the End Times? Given the preponderance of literature, popular and otherwise, that focuses on the end of the world, it stands to reason there should be a specific term for this specific, ostensibly pleasurable manifestation of a mass death wish. There's this Reddit post, which discusses it: [Is there a word for the longing for apocalypse/end of civilization?](https://www.reddit.com/r/neology/comments/2nhkln/is_there_a_word_for_the_longing_for_apocalypseend/)

But "eschatomania," a more Judeo-Christian term referring to "an intensive preoccupation with the prophetic passages or details of the Bible, eschatological charts, prophecy studies, end-times predictions and preaching, etc." is the only real word posted there. Is there another, better and/or less religiously-oriented word or phrase for "Apocalyptaphilia"? Or should we just start using that? :)

Comment: As there is only the religious who speak of this a "less religiously-oriented word" is going to be difficult... The other point is that, theologically, all Christians are looking forward to this event, thus only "eschatophobia" is a useful word.

Comment: 'Misguided' springs to mind. Unless one has a firm belief in the coming consummation  'Heaven and Earth in sync' [Johnny Carr] Kingdom of God and is sure one has a place paid for.

Comment: @Boaz Well, I'm sure there are a few Walking Dead fans who may be non-denominational, where not outright atheists — and then, there's non-religious me — so, I doubt its "only the religious who speak of this." And I'm asking about desire, not fear, so no "phobias" would apply here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why "misguided"? Don't some people wishing for the End Times intend to rot in hell?

Comment: @Boaz Nah, it wouldn't.

Comment: @Boaz Possibly! I mention Walking Dead, but it could just easily be, say, Will Forte's The Last Man on Earth, &c., &c., &c.: there's this fascination with the Apocalypse that, I think, is unique and nameable. And, to be sure, doomy — just not "doomsayer," though I wouldn't put it past any such aficionado.

Comment: Man, leave it to the Germans: I found this episode of a podcast titled: "Sehnsucht nach der Apokalypse," or "longing for the Apocalypse": [link](https://www.amazon.com/Sehnsucht-nach-der-Apokalypse/dp/B08K6MY1F9) . That's it!! Just not in English... :/

Comment: @Boaz That's "the religious belief that there will be an apocalypse." Leaving aside the religiosity, I'm looking for a term for the longing for it, not the belief in it.

Comment: Deleted my own comments to avoid this thread becoming too long. I just want to point out that it's difficult to take the religious connotation out of a human construct that is based in religion to begin with.

Comment: @Boaz Hmmmmm!!! Intriguing...I need to think about this some more (and I don't care how long this thread is! :D ), but I wonder if that's the case. Think of Mary Shelley's _The Last Man_ — isn't part of its appeal to readers identification with that last person's "lastness"? That desire doesn't strike me as related to religion in any particular way.

Comment: The stereotypical ***doomsday prophet*** is a guy walking the streets in a sandwich board claiming *The end of the world is nigh*. But they're been doing that ever since sandwich boards were invented, and they've never been right yet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They only need to be right once.

Comment: @jimiayler: Pigs only need to fly once to make us to dump that idiomatic usage. But I ain't holding my breath! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Pigs flying sounds pretty apocalyptic to me.

Answer (score 1):

### Catastrophism

Wired's article ['This is Not The Apocalypse You Were Looking For'](https://www.wired.com/story/coronavirus-apocalypse-myths/) offers lots of ways of talking about those who seem to yearn for the end of the world.

For a single-word choice, there's **catastrophism**. This is [defined more often](https://www.google.com/search?q=catastrophism) as

> The theory that changes in the earth's crust during geological history have resulted chiefly from sudden violent and unusual events.

But there is a [second definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/catastrophism) available in American English:

> an outlook envisioning imminent catastrophe

[For example](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/catastrophism): *In contrast, the rest of the right offered "catastrophism": the conviction that the Republic could be overthrown only by violence.*

Comment: That's a great word, but I'm looking for a some "consummation devoutly to be wish'd" with my "outlook envisioning"

Comment: Hmm. OK. I've tried again with 'Millenarianism', but it might still have too many religious overtones.

Comment: No; envisioning does not entail desire.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course, it depends what you're envisioning, but envisioning does not, in and of itself, imply desire.

Answer (score -1):

### Millenarianism

Originally Millenarinism was a wholly Christian concept, based on the 'Millenium' of the Book of Revelation, which foretells a 1000-year period of direct rule of humankind by God, after a great catastrophe.

> Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection. Over these the second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ, and they will reign with him **a thousand years.** - [Revelation ch. 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennialism)

However the definition has widened to (as here in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/millenarianism)):

> belief in a coming ideal society and especially one created by revolutionary action

As per Wikipedia:

> Increasingly in the study of apocalyptic new religious movements, millenarianism is used to refer to a **more cataclysmic and destructive arrival of a utopian period...**

Comment: Per my earlier comment above: "belief" might incorporate but is not iself "longing for."

Comment: If you believe in something good to come, it's implied that you are longing for it.

Comment: @StuartF If only "belief" always implied "something good to come": I believe in the End Times, but I don't long for them.

Answer (score -1):

## Accelerationism

might suit your needs, but be warned it is a philosophy and not just a feeling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think it could potentially answer the question, but I do see that I wasn't clear enough about the word. I've edited my answer slightly.

Comment: I think this bends Accelerationism past any of the various existing uses. Follow the link the bot provided to see how to flesh out an answer, so you can better make an argument. It'll likely to closed otherwise.

Comment: I agree with @jimm101 here: accelerationism may be the result of a desire for Apocalypse, but not a term which defines that desire.